# Duvida de como pegar um JSON, transformar em objeto

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Estou com uma pequena duvida em relação a um modulo json em c++, queria saber se existe alguma forma de pegar um json que já existe e incrementar mais campos usando c++,

```
json data = json::parse(getData());
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen("data.json", "a");
fputs("", pFile);
fclose(pFile);

{
"0": {
"area": "SI",
"codigo_curso": "01",
"cpf": "000.000.000-00",
"data_nascimento": "00/00/0000",
"descricao": "Breve",
"endereco": "00000-000",
"nome": "Daniel Yohan"
}
}
```

queria adicionar mais desses aqui com valores alterados:

```
"0": {
"area": "SI",
"codigo_curso": "01",
"cpf": "000.000.000-00",
"data_nascimento": "00/00/0000",
"descricao": "Breve",
"endereco": "00000-000",
"nome": "Daniel Yohan"
}
```

estou usando a lib https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Alguém saberia como fazer pra eu carregar o meu json atual depois adicionar e salvar novamente? ficarei grato, isso é pra um trabalho da faculdade. Obrigado

Comment: E que lib é esta que está usando de json?

Comment: como falei, estou usando a biblioteca https://github.com/nlohmann/json , lá tem a lib do json

Comment: Desculpe quando disse "estou usando o json do" eu entendi que era um arquivo json, agora ficou mais claro, veja se a resposta funciona por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que conforme o README seja assim https://github.com/nlohmann/json#json-as-first-class-data-type, ficaria algo assim:

```
json newitem = {
"area": "SI",
"codigo_curso": "02",
"cpf": "000.000.000-00",
"data_nascimento": "00/00/0000",
"descricao": "Breve",
"endereco": "00000-000",
"nome": "João"
};

json data = json::parse(getData());
data["1"] = newitem;
```

Para gravar trocaria o `a` por `w`, ou melhor trocaria FILE por `ofstream` pra não ter que ficar fazendo conversões e usaria `dump()` (ou `.dump(4)` para colocar espaçamentos) para converter para texto:

```
string jsonstr = j.dump();

ofstream arq;
arq.open("data.json");
arq << jsonstr;
arq.close();
```

Assim vai atualizar o arquivo atual